# How to work with Laravel and Vue to develop a system

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I'm about to start developing a system and I'm going to use Laravel with Vue on it.
I'm learning Laravel a little bit and time and I'm starting at Vue, so I'd like some tips:

What would be the best structure for the system:

- Laravel serving the data and templates and Vue doing only the part of the scripts on the front or;
- Vue doing all the visual part, both on the front and backend and doing an API in Laravel to process the data?

If you're going to separate Vue from Laravel, authentication would be on Laravel. In this case, would the frontend pages in Vue always be available to the user and only access to the data by the API would be authenticated? Or is it possible in the backend with Vue to do validation in the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the place we work we use Vue + Laravel. The backend developers do all the stuff related to the database and the api services. They give us the endpoints so we can retrieve the data.

We (the frontend developers) take the endpoints and we do all the job to get the data. We use Vuex to create all the store and the functions we need to retrieve what we need. And it works very well.

I think it is better to let Laravel do all the data management and do the other parts in Vue.

All is in its place, for me it is easier to understand.

Comment: I think it's the same thing.
But how do you work with validation to access pages?
In another project, when a user requests the page and does not have permission, I return the menu with a "Permission Denied" message in the content body.
Is it possible to do this with Vue in the backend?

Comment: I think that is better to left clear that Vue is a frontend framework. So, develop the backend in Vue is not possible. Read this article https://masteringbackend.com/posts/vue-js-for-backend-developers/